# Log to database

Tags: r, logging

Trying to redirect `message`, `warning`, and `error` to a database, I came up with a kind of decorator function:

```
with_db_log <- function(expr, con=NULL) {
    stopifnot(!is.null(con))
    do_log <- function(lvl, cnd) {
        if(inherits(con, "try-error")) return()
        dat <- data.frame(
            ts=strftime(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
            lvl=lvl,
            msg=trimws(conditionMessage(cnd)),
            stringsAsFactors=FALSE
        )
        DBI::dbWriteTable(con, name="log", value=dat, append=TRUE) 
    }
    
    tryCatch(
        error = function(cnd) {
            do_log(lvl="error", cnd=cnd)
            invisible(structure(conditionMessage(cnd), class = "try-error", condition = cnd))
        },
        withCallingHandlers(
            message = function(cnd) {do_log(lvl="message", cnd=cnd)},
            warning = function(cnd) {do_log(lvl="warning", cnd=cnd)},
            expr
        )
    )
}
```

where `con` is a living database connection. Now to redirect errors, warnings and diagnostic messages, I can do

```
with_db_log(con=my_db_connection, 
    my_function(my_param)
)
```

and the database table `log` with columns `ts`, `lvl` and `msg` gets updated.

(I used stackoverflow to write the code, but can not find the link anymore.)

However, it seems not to work in all cases: sometimes the `msg` field remains empty. It is not so easy for me to find out what cases these are. I suspect that there is a problem with the code above:

```
msg=trimws(conditionMessage(cnd))
```

but I can not find what the problem is.

Is there a better way to extract a log message from a condition? Any hints appreciated.